# Add several emails and diplay defined values

Tags: angularjs, forms, email, html-email

My form allows to update and add several emails. The first email field (main email) is mandatory. After filling it's possible to click on a button "Add email" for adding a new email address. By this way it's possible to add 4 others emails (5 emails in total).

The system checks if the format of the email is correct and displays a message if necessary and register the data in a DB.

***Here my view (manageContact.html)***

```
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form name="ContactForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form" novalidate ng-submit="submitForm(contact)">

    <!---------------- FOR UPDATING EMAILS FIELDS ------------ START --->   

    <div ng-repeat="(key, email) in emails | limitTo : 5" style="z-index:6">

      <div class="form-group">

        <span ng-switch="$index">
            <label ng-switch-when="0" for="txtEmail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Main email</label>
            <label ng-switch-default for="txtEmail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email {{$index+1}}</label>
        </span> 

        <div class="col-sm-9" ng-switch="$index">

            <input ng-switch-when="0" type="email" class="form-control"
            name="txtEmail_{{$index}}" maxlength="100" placeholder="Enter main email"
            ng-model="contact.EMAIL">       

            <input ng-switch-default type="email" class="form-control" 
            name="txtEmail_{{$index}}" maxlength="100" placeholder="Enter Email {{$index+1}}" 
            ng-model="contact['EMAIL_'+$index]">    

            <div class="error-container" 
             ng-show="ContactForm['txtEmail_' + $index].$dirty && ContactForm['txtEmail_' + $index].$invalid">
                <div ng-show="ContactForm['txtEmail_' + $index].$error.email" class="alert alert-info" role="alert" style="margin-top:10px;">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-alert" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
                  That is not a valid email. Please input a valid email.
                </div>

                <div ng-show="ContactForm['txtEmail_' + $index].$error.required" class="alert alert-info" role="alert" style="margin-top:10px;">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-alert" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
                  Your email is required.
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div  class="col-sm-1" ng-show="$index == 0">
            <a href="" ng-click="add()" ng-show="emails.length<5" class="inline btn btn-primary icon_email">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus icon2"></span><span class="addButton">Add email</span>
            </a>
        </div>  

      </div>

    </div>
    <!---------------- FOR UPDATING EMAILS FIELDS ------------ END ---> 

    </form> 
  </div>
```

In order to see all emails registered of the contact, it's necessary with my current script to click on the button "Add email" each time that an email is registered for seeing data.

I would like to display the emails if they exist in the DB - so display each time the row (field + data). If it doesn't exist it's necessary to click on the button for adding an new email.

I have problem for doing that into my ng-switch and I don't how to do that in another way.

***Here my controlers "ctrlEditContacts" and module (app.js):***

```
    var app=angular.module('ContactsApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngDialog']);

    app.factory('HttpInterceptor', ['$q', '$rootScope', function($q, $rootScope) {
           return {
                ......
                }
            };

    app.config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, ngDialogProvider){

        ...  
    });             


    app.controller('ctrlEditContacts', function ($scope, $routeParams, MyTextSearch, ContactService, ngDialog, $timeout){

    //FOR ALLOWING SEVERAL EMAILS
    $scope.emails = [
    {
    }];
    $scope.log = function() {
      console.log($scope.emails);
    };
    $scope.add = function() {
        var dataObj = {email:''};       
        $scope.emails.push(dataObj);
    }

    ContactService.loadPersonById($routeParams.contactId).success(function(contact){    
        $scope.contact.ID = contact[0].ID;  
        $scope.contact.EMAIL = contact[0].EMAIL;
        $scope.contact.EMAIL_1 = contact[0].EMAIL_1;
        $scope.contact.EMAIL_2 = contact[0].EMAIL_2;
        $scope.contact.EMAIL_3 = contact[0].EMAIL_3;
        $scope.contact.EMAIL_4 = contact[0].EMAIL_4;                
    })
    .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
        ...     
    }).finally(function() {   
        ...     
    });             

    $scope.submitForm = function(contact){      
        if($scope.ContactForm.$valid){
            ContactService.updatePerson(contact, $routeParams.contactId).success(function(){
                alert('Person updated successfully');
            })
            .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
            })
            .finally(function() {
            });                     
        }
    };  

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry if I'm misunderstanding.
In this case, you need to loop for the number of contact's email info.
For example, if you get a kind of data below; you need to loop three times.

```
$scope.contact.ID = contact[0].ID;  
$scope.contact.EMAIL = contact[0].EMAIL;      // 'test1@mail.com'
$scope.contact.EMAIL_1 = contact[0].EMAIL_1;  // 'test2@mail.com'
$scope.contact.EMAIL_2 = contact[0].EMAIL_2;  // 'test3@mail.com'
$scope.contact.EMAIL_3 = contact[0].EMAIL_3;  // ''
$scope.contact.EMAIL_4 = contact[0].EMAIL_4;  // ''
// So 'emails' should be modified at this timing.
$scope.emails = [];
// Just for loop, so it doesn't matter what value you add.
$scope.emails.push($scope.contact.EMAIL);
$scope.emails.push($scope.contact.EMAIL_1);
$scope.emails.push($scope.contact.EMAIL_2);
```

After that, changing 'Add email' condition.

```
ng-show="$index == emails.length - 1"
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dhwyp7uo/2/)

Comment: Thanks for that. I don't understand when I apply that the row about the defined email is not directly displayed by default. I have to click on "Add email" in order to see the field with the value. In our case I can see the main email but not the email_1, email_2 and email_3.In order to see them I must click on the button. I try to start from scratch but it's the same problem. I'm using AngularJS v1.3.0

Comment: When I do `{{emails}}` above the ng-repeat I obtain [{}] in the view and not the values registered. Could you please help me?

Comment: Yes, that is because you push data to ‘$scope.emails’ only when you hit the add button. So simply, you need to add elements when you get the person data as I wrote above.

Comment: You can see the number of fields as the same number of length of ‘$scope.emails’ , and currently, there’s no link between ‘$scope.emails’ and the email info of ‘$scope.contact’. So you have to adjust to work properly.